# Rank values of an array in R with apply

Tags: r, arrays, sorting, rank

I need to rank the values of an array, on the third axe.
I have an array like so :

```
a <- array(c(1:9,11:19,21:29),dim = c(3,3,3))
```

The expected result is an matrix with the rank of the first one, that I expected to compute like this : `apply(X = a, MARGIN = c(1,2), FUN = rank)[, ,1]`

```
# expected result because a[,,1] is the minimal value of my array
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

However the `apply` function return me another array, which is strange because it return a matrix when I use other functions like `mean`, `max` or `sort`.

I've checked that `apply(a, c(1,2), print)` and it print the vector I'm interested in ranking (example it print `1 11 21` on the first iteration).

I can code this with a for-loop but at least I'm curious on what exactly is the issue in this case.

```
# The for loop to obtain the good result
a2 <- a[,,1]
for(i in seq(dim(a)[1])){
  for(j in seq(dim(a)[2])){
    a2[i,j] <- rank(a[i,j,])[1]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[1,,]` instead of `[,,1]`, i.e.,

```
apply(X = a, MARGIN = c(1,2), FUN = rank)[1,,]
```

such that

```
> apply(X = a, MARGIN = c(1,2), FUN = rank)[1,,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

Comment: It works but I don't really understand why...do you have an explanation ?

Comment: `[1,,]` means that you access the first rows of the the "cube" (you have three dimensions). You can try `a[2,,]`, `a[,2,]`,`a[,,2]` to see how it presents `a` along certain dimensions

Comment: Yes I got that, but I don't understant why the cude orientation changed when using the rank function. Why the `apply[,,1]` isn't the same 'face' as a[,,1] ? For me it look like there was a sort of 'rotation' in the 'cube' during the computation.

Comment: @Gowachin `apply(a, c(1,2), ...)` runs along the the 3rd dimension,  which works over the plane spanned by the 1st and 2nd dimensions (i.e., `c(1,2)`). In that case, the results of rank 1 are actually present on the plane by 2nd and 3rd dimensions, so you need `apply(a,c(1,2),...)[1,,]`...Maybe it's hard to clarify it by words, but you can try to plot a cube to visualize the process

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
apply(a, c(1,2), function(x) rank(x)[1])

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1
```